# My C++ program in SFML 2.3 crashes on startup

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sfml

So I've been working on a program that creates a database of reports. I've been working on this for a few weeks with a multitude of SFML related problems (as I am having to learn this library.) I finally managed to overcome a library limitation, when I am suddenly presented with a new problem. When I launch the program, I am greeted with the command console. No biggie, that's normal. Then I am greeted by the window saying that it's suddenly stopped working. After running the debugger, this is where it breaks:

```
#ifdef WPRFLAG
        __winitenv = envp;
        mainret = wmain(argc, argv, envp);

#else  /* WPRFLAG */

        __initenv = envp;

        mainret = main(argc, argv, envp); // <-- This is where it's breaking
#endif  /* WPRFLAG */

#endif  /* _WINMAIN_ */

        /*
         * Note that if the exe is managed app, we don't really need to
         * call exit or _c_exit. .cctor should be able to take care of
         * this.
         */
```

I don't understand why it's breaking there, or how to fix it. Please help, I've been researching to no avail for hours.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Did an exception get thrown? Did any message show up in the console? There could be many reasons with it breaks there. We'll need more info to diagnose.

Comment: Well, I would've posted a picture, but I "have to have 10 reputation." Because of that, I forgot to mention that it's some "chkstk()" function or something. It's from stack frame: _tmainCRTStartup. basically, it's crashing somewhere that I haven't written code. Here's an imgur link to the screenshot I took: [link](http://imgur.com/129W9Gz)

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Um, I don't know what that is. I have only finished my first year studying for Computer Science, so I'm pretty new.

Comment: You don't need to post a screen shot; instead copy the text to the clipboard and then paste into your question.  Do not paste code into comments.

Comment: @LizardBoi I got the acronim wrong ;/ [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a clickable link that explains what it means. Its a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example`. If your program crashes at startup maybe its enough to post only the initialization code that leads to the problem.

Comment: Well, my whole program is close to 4000 lines and it's not done. The problem with posting the code, is that I don't know where the problem is, and it's breaking in code that I haven't written, thus the screenshot to show whats breaking and where.

Comment: @LizardBoi: 1. Show us the call stack from the debugger. 2. Look through the call stack to find the closest code that is yours to where it's breaking. 3. Post that code here. Or, if this is too complicated or time consuming, perhaps use http://pastebin.com/ to show it to us. We need more info to really nail this down for you, please.

Comment: An exception in `chkstk` means you have a stack overflow.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee that would indicate he's got a recursive function that isn't terminating before blowing out the stack, right?

Comment: @erapert: No, it could be caused by recursion, allocating too much memory on the stack, or stack corruption.

Comment: Well, I'm not doing any recursion so it *shouldn't* be having a problem with it. Well, what the debugger said is the call stack is as follows:
 
cannon.exe!_chkstk() Line 99
cannon.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 626 C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
 
As I said earlier, I'm rather new to programming as a whole, so I had to look up what call stack even was XD As far as closest code to mine, all the code is in this code that I haven't written. (The stack doesn't want to stay spaced out nicely)